# How to Set the RelativeLayout to ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

As we usually see, the listview is **rendered line by line.**

But I want to set its items anywhere in it by setting the item's left and top. And first of all, I think the listview require another layout such as relativelayout.right?
so my question is can we Set a RelativeLayout to ListView? how?

My code is

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
```

unfortunately,it doesn't work!

but the code below works fine:

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
```

Can Somebody tell me what's wrong with it? Is there some better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need ListView at all.
As the reference says http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html ListView can only show items in vertically scrolling list.
Just create relative layout and add child views manually.

Answer (score 0):

Create XML file something like this for `ListView` items:

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/text1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in `ListView_Adapter` class do:

```
public class ListView_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public ListView_Adapter(Context c)
    {
        super(c, R.layout.listview_item);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
  //
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me what shold I do in the adapter class?